# Не срабатывает повторный запрос к базе данных

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, postgresql

Файл базы данных SelectDb.js

```
module.exports = new promise(function(resolve,reject){
pool.connect(function(err,client,done){
    if(err) console.log(err.toString());
    else {
        client.query('SELECT text FROM public.message;', function (err, 
result) {
            done();

            console.log("I make new Request");
            if(result) {
                resolve(result);
                //client.end();
            }
        })
    }
    });
 })
```

При первом запросе я получаю данные из бд, при повторном не срабатывает. При добавлении данных в базе данных отображаются в самой базе данных,а повторный запрос присылает не обновленные данные,а первоначальные. 
Я не понимаю, я сам должен закрыть соединение и сделать повторно запрос,что бы получить обновленные данные?
`done()`  разместил в нужном мне месте, согласно документации.
Пытаясь закрыть мне выдает ошибку:

> Error [ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END]: write after end

Как я понимаю не туда сую закрытие или нафиг ты закрываешь если я еще не вернул данные. Я не уверен что я вообще понимаю какие действия требуются для адекватной работы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Суть, просто вызываю функцию. И все проблемы решены.
Не знаю на сколько это правильно.

```
module.exports.SelMsg = function MsgSel(){
return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
pool.connect()
    .then(function (client) {
        client.query('SELECT text FROM public.message;')

            .then(function (res) {
                resolve(res);
                client.release();
            }).catch(function (e) {
            console.log(e);
        })

    })
    })
   }
```